# Autoware.Auto ROS2Bag compatibility with Point Cloud Map Builder

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbag, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a Livox Lidar which we plan to use to map out a route which can be used with the Autoware.Auto track. We noticed that using this tool:  https://tools.tier4.jp/feature/point_cloud_map_builder/ we can convert a .bag to .pcd . Is it compatible with ROS2 bags? Or should we just record it with a ROS1 bag

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378634/autoware.auto-ros2bag-compatibility-with-point-cloud-map-builder/) by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2021-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not but it also should not be necessary. See my answer to https://answers.ros.org/question/378637/autowareauto-best-way-to-create-a-pcd-map/ for a tool in Autoware.Auto that will allow you to do this.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0